# getting error while applying SciPy stats.contingency on a DataFrame to findout critical value and p value of data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, statistics, data-science

I am trying to check relationship between gender and destination country columns of below DF

```
              id    gender  country_destination
   2    4ft3gnwmtx  FEMALE  US
   6    lsw9q7uk0j  FEMALE  US
   7    0d01nltbrs  FEMALE  US
   8    a1vcnhxeij  FEMALE  US
  10    yuuqmid2rp  FEMALE  US
```

To apply stat.chi2_contingency and get p value I have converted this table to pivot_table as below:

```
       AU   CA  DE  ES  FR  GB  IT  NL  PT  US
gender                                      
FEMALE 207  455 358 853 1962 88 1091 254 78 22694
MALE   188  477 416 677 1335 682 699 278 69 19457
```

But I am getting below error when i execute
**stats.chi2_contingency(df_contingency)**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-fee39cdf166f> in <module>()
----> 1 stats.chi2_contingency(df_contingency)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/stats/contingency.py in 
chi2_contingency(observed, correction, lambda_)
    243     observed = np.asarray(observed)
--> 244     if np.any(observed < 0):
    245         raise ValueError("All values in `observed` must be nonnegative.")
    246     if observed.size == 0:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Plese help me in understanding where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you did something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

np.random.seed(111)

dat = pd.DataFrame({'gender':np.random.choice(['MALE','FEMALE'],100),
                  'country_destination':np.random.choice(['AU','CA','DE','ES','FR'],100)})

pt = dat.pivot_table(columns='country_destination',index='gender',
values='country_destination',aggfunc=len)

country_destination AU  CA  DE  ES  FR
gender                  
FEMALE  6   12  12  9   15
MALE    8   9   12  4   13
```

Contingency on this works:

```
chi2_contingency(pt)
```

So will if you do crosstab instead of pivot:

```
chi2_contingency(pd.crosstab(dat['gender'],dat['country_destination']))
```

Most likely you need to provide the count that leads up to the contingency table